# requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool How can I solve it?

Tags: python, proxy

I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 364, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 501, in _connect_tls_proxy
    socket = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 453, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 495, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ipinfo.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /json (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\text.py", line 7, in <module>
    response = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/json', proxies=proxies)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ipinfo.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /json (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)')))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Do I need to download any pip SSL? Or is it because of a proxy problem? Or add a pip to IDE like "Pycharm"?
I get every time error even when I change a proxy.
my code:

```
import requests
proxies = {
    'https': 'https://150.129.148.99:35101'
}
response = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/json', proxies=proxies)
print(response.json()['country'])
print(response.json()['region'])
```

This is a video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnIye9pM22w` in min `5:21` that I copied his code, and just for him it works and for me it does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely a problem with proxy.

You can check it with `curl` like this:

```sh
curl -v -x https://150.129.148.99:35101 ipinfo.io
```

You'll have:

```
*   Trying 150.129.148.99...
* TCP_NODELAY set
```

And nothing more. That means the proxy server doesn't respond correctly.

Comment: Will it work on Windows?

Comment: [`curl`](https://curl.se/windows/) for windows. Or [with your browser](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-proxy-server-all-major-internet-browsers-windows/).

Comment: I always get an error

Comment: The issue is with your proxy. It doesn't works, you can't fix it on your computer.

Comment: need I download any SSL pip?

Comment: Again, your proxy `https://150.129.148.99:35101` doesn't work; you need to change it for the working one. Downloading anything won't help you.

Comment: I used it ```C:\Users\user>curl -v -x https://59.66.17.194:7890 google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: google.com/
* Unsupported proxy 'https://59.66.17.194:7890', libcurl is built without the HTTPS-proxy support.
* Closing connection -1
curl: (4) Unsupported proxy 'https://59.66.17.194:7890', libcurl is built without the HTTPS-proxy support.``` Now a new mistake I got, is it a desirable mistake worth checking out like this or am I not doing something right again?

Comment: [As I found](https://audministrator.wordpress.com/2019/08/06/windows-10-curl-protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl-error/), you need to surround proxy with double quotes if using windows, like this: `curl -v -x "https://150.129.148.99:35101" ipinfo.io`. And use `ipinfo.io` for tests, google might ban you for programmatic requests.

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Comment: So did it help you? Did you figure out your issue?

Comment: I found another working proxy , and used command ```curl -v -x "http://182.253.21.26:46977" ipinfo.io``` and it worked but without the `https`

Comment: I don't know why it worked without `https`

Comment: Possibly you really had downloaded some version of `curl` where `HTTPS-proxy` support was disabled. And `curl` used `HTTP` protocol which worked.

Comment: Is it possible to fix it?